# Find the two compass directions of a level path on a surface, $z=2000 - 0.02x^2 - 0.04y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Suppose the elevation $z$ above a point $(x,y)$ in an $xy-$plane at sea level is given by $ \ z \  = \  2000 - 0.02x^2 - 0.04y^2 \ $. Assume that the positive $x-$axis is oriented due east and the positive $y-$axis points due north. If a hiker is standing at the point $ \ (-20  , \ 5, \ 1991) \ $ , determine 2 compass directions in which the hiker can walk to travel a level path.

So I found the partial derivative of $z$ which is $ \ -0.04x\hat{i} - 0.08y\hat{j} \ $ and then plugged in $(-20,5)$ to find $\nabla z$ which is $ \ 0.8\hat{i}-0.4\hat{j} \ $ but I have no idea how to find vectors perpendicular to $\nabla z$ since it's a level path. Help with steps would be appreciated. I just know the dot product has to equal 0.

The book solution says $\hat i + 2\hat j$ and $\hat i-2\hat j$ are vectors that would satisfy but how would that work since the dot product of these vectors don't equal 0?

Comment: What is a level path? Is it not a curve given by the equation $z_0=f(x,y)$? In our case the level path is $-0.02x^2-0.04y^2+1=0$. Sorry if I am mistaken.

Comment: It says the for the climber to travel a level path, he has to move in directions perpendicular to delta z therefore the dot product of two perpendicular vectors must equal 0.

Comment: Isn't there an independent geometric definition for a _level path_?

Comment: @zoli: You could write down an equation for the level curve, yes (but it would be $9$ instead of $1$).  You could use that to answer the question, which involves finding the tangent directions to the curve at the given point. The method Jizibel refers to is using the fact that the level curves are perpendicular to the gradient vectors.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yes (2000 -1991=1 for me :). Thank you. So, this must be a homework problem with an obligatory method of solution.

Answer (score 0):

A vector perpendicular to $a\mathbf{i}+b\mathbf{j}$ is $c(-b \mathbf{i} + a \mathbf{j})$ (as you can verify by computing the dot product). Using this you can find the perpendicular vector.

Comment: So would it just be -0.4i + 0.8j / magnitude?

Comment: You said you computed $\nabla z$ to be $0.8\textbf i - 0.4\textbf j$. In this case, the vector perpendicular to $\nabla z$ would be $(0.4\textbf i + 0.8\textbf j)/\text{magnitude}$. Note the negative sign next to $b$ and no negative sign next to $a$ in the perpendicular vector.